# How can I use ajax to retrieve remote json file

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

```
$.ajax({
  //url: "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PjXOSVsTCMBti9CyT3l5UmiThCcn1ziU/view",
  url: "myfile.json",
  data: "{}",
  type: "GET",
  async: "true",
  dataType: "json",
  jsonp: "callback",
  jsonpCallback: "jsonpCallbackfunction",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",      
  success: function(result)
  {
    console.log(result);
    var output="";
    for (var i in result)
    {
        output+= "<div class='swiper-slide swiper-zoom-container'><img style='width:100%; height:100%;' src='" + result[i].url +  "' /></div>";
    }

    index.html(output);
```

When using the local file all is working great. When try to use remote file, I get no thing. I heard about same origin but I want a solution.

thanks

Comment: What did you hear about the same origin?

Comment: CORS problem, look about this

Comment: Make sure endpoint supports jsonp requests.

Comment: It doesn't look like google drive supports jsonp.

Comment: Try downloading with the **dataType** set to **text** and then running [**JSON.parse()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on the contents of the file.